# Errno 13 Permission denied: '/storage/emulated/0/Download/ kivy app on androd

Tags: android, python-3.x, permissions, kivy, android-permissions

I have error 13 Permission denied, when I try to read  a picture from /storage/emulated/0/Download/ using the open function and the kivy.

App works without error on motorola g32 with android 12 but doesn't work on honor 10 lite with android 10 and redmi with android 12

I add in buildozer.spec permissions:
android.permissions = WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEVx0.png)

```
# https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD/blob/master/kivymd/icon_definitions.py
from kivymd.app import MDApp
# from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from plyer import filechooser
import sys
from kivy.utils import platform
from datetime import datetime


kv = """
<Demo>

    orientation: "vertical"

    MDBottomNavigation:
        panel_color: "#800080"
        text_color_active: "F5F5F5"
        MDBottomNavigationItem:

            name: "screen 1"
            text: "Головна"
            icon: "google-earth"
            MDLabel:
                id: Vitalii
                text: "@created by "
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.7,"center_y":0.03}
            MDLabel:
                id: descr
                text: "Цей додаток працює із зображеннями фомату bmp(bitmap), та символами таблиці ACII(Англійський алфавіт), якщо виникли питання зверніться  телеграм"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.55,"center_y":0.5}
                size_hint: (0.8,0.5)








        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: "screen 2"
            text: "Зашифрувати"
            icon: "file-code"

            MDLabel:
                id: selected_path
                text: "Введіть текст"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.6,"center_y":0.88}

            MDLabel:
                id: seria1
                text: "seria 1"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.7,"center_y":0.5}

            MDCheckbox:
                group: "Encrypt_seria" 
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.12,"center_y":0.5}
                size_hint: (0.1,0.07)
                on_active: root.Encrypt_checkbox_click(self, self.active, "seria1")

            MDLabel:
                id: seria2
                text: "seria 2"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 1,"center_y":0.5}

            MDCheckbox:
                group: "Encrypt_seria"
                size_hint: (0.1,0.07)
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.425,"center_y":0.5}
                on_active: root.Encrypt_checkbox_click(self, self.active, "seria2")

            MDLabel:
                id: seria3
                text: "seria 3"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 1.3,"center_y":0.5}

            MDCheckbox:
                group: "Encrypt_seria" 
                size_hint: (0.1,0.07)
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.725,"center_y":0.5}
                on_active: root.Encrypt_checkbox_click(self, self.active, "seria3")

            TextInput:
                id: inp1
                size_hint: (0.8,0.3)
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5,"center_y":0.7}
            Button:
                text: "Обрати файл"
                bold: True
                background_color:'00FFCE'
                size_hint: (0.8,0.2)
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5,"center_y":0.34}
                on_press: root.callback()
            Button:
                text: "Зашифрувати"
                bold: True
                background_color:'00FFCE'
                size_hint: (0.8,0.2)
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5,"center_y":0.12}
                on_press: root.encrypt()

        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: "screen 3"
            text: "Розшифрувати"
            icon: "file-document"
            MDLabel:
                id: selected_path
                text: 
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.6,"center_y":0.98}
            MDLabel:
                id: seria1
                text: "seria 1"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.7,"center_y":0.5}

            MDCheckbox:
                group: "Decrypt_seria" 
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.12,"center_y":0.5}
                size_hint: (0.1,0.07)
                on_active: root.Decrypt_checkbox_click(self, self.active, "seria1")

            MDLabel:
                id: seria2
                text: "seria 2"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 1,"center_y":0.5}

            MDCheckbox:
                group: "Decrypt_seria" 
                size_hint: (0.1,0.07)
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.425,"center_y":0.5}
                on_active: root.Decrypt_checkbox_click(self, self.active, "seria2")

            MDLabel:
                id: seria3
                text: "seria 3"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 1.3,"center_y":0.5}

            MDCheckbox:
                group: "Decrypt_seria" 
                size_hint: (0.1,0.07)
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.725,"center_y":0.5}
                on_active: root.Decrypt_checkbox_click(self, self.active, "seria3")

            TextInput:
                id: inp2
                text:
                size_hint: (0.8,0.4)
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5,"center_y":0.76}

            Button:
                text: "Обрати файл"
                bold: True
                background_color:'00FFCE'
                size_hint: (0.8,0.2)
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5,"center_y":0.34}
                on_press: root.callback()
            Button:
                text: "Розкодувати"
                bold: True
                background_color:'00FFCE'
                size_hint: (0.8,0.2)
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5,"center_y":0.12}
                on_press: root.decrypt()






"""


class Demo(BoxLayout):
    global degree
    degree = 1
    Encrypt_checks = []
    Decrypt_checks = []

    def converter_to_bmp(self,path):
        from PIL import Image
        Image.open("sample1.png").save("sample1.bmp")

    def Encrypt_checkbox_click(self, instance, value, topping):
        if value == True:
            Demo.Encrypt_checks.append(topping)
        else:
            Demo.Encrypt_checks.remove(topping)

    def Decrypt_checkbox_click(self, instance, value, topping):
        if value == True:
            Demo.Decrypt_checks.append(topping)
        else:
            Demo.Decrypt_checks.remove(topping)


        

    def decrypt(self):
        try:
            encoded_bmp = open(choice_picture, "rb")

        except:
            self.ids.inp2.text = str(sys.exc_info()[1])

    def encrypt(self):
        try:
            text = self.ids.inp1.text + "!"
            start_bmp = open(choice_picture, 'rb')
            if platform == "android":
                encode_bmp = open(f'/storage/emulated/0/Download/encoded_{time_now}.bmp', 'wb')
             
            encode_bmp.write(start_bmp.read())
            start_bmp.close()
            encode_bmp.close()
            self.ids.inp1.text =  f"Файл збережено у папку Download під назвою: encoded_{time_now}.bmp"
        except:
            self.ids.inp1.text = str(sys.exc_info()[1])

    def callback(self):
        filechooser.open_file(on_selection=self.selected)

    def selected(self, selection):
        # try:
        if selection:

            global choice_picture
            choice_picture = selection[0]
            self.ids.selected_path.text = choice_picture

        # except:
        # self.ids.inp2.text = str(sys.exc_info()[1])


class Main(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv)
        return Demo()

    def on_start(self):
        if platform == 'android':
            from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
            request_permissions([Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])

    def process1(self):
        text = self.root.ids.Inp1.text


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main().run()
```

Comment: That picture was not created by your app.

Comment: on motorola g32 andriod 12 this app open picture and create the picture correct, but on honnor 10 lite android 10 and Redmi android 12 i have Errno 13 Permission denied: '/storage/emulated/0/Download/encoded.bmp

Comment: That picture was not created by your app.

Comment: I don’t understand how this explains the fact that it works on one phone and not on the other, but then how can I open the picture for binary reading

Comment: On Android 11+ devices apps have no access to files of other apps when they are not media files.

Comment: `on motorola g32 andriod 12 this app open picture and create the picture correct` Sorry i cannot follow you. If they can open that file then it exists. So it cannot be created then.

Comment: I open any picture of the download directory and rewrite this picture with a different name

Comment: If you can open a file then you will read it. But in your post on the first lines you tell that you cannot read that file. Pretty unclear what you mean and do.

Comment: I mean that on the phone motorola g32 android 12 the application opens any picture without errors, and on the phone honor 10 lite android 10 and the phone Redmi android 12 it gives the error Errno 13 Permission denied: '/storage/emulated/0/Download/encoded .bmp and I don't understand why and how to fix it, I thought it was because of EMUI and MIUI that it's not pure Android but a modification, and how to fix it on these systems

Comment: You already told that in your post. This does not help at all.

Comment: i tried my app on android 10 with EMUI on honor 10 lite. i tried my app on motorola g32 android 12 and app work correct. How i can open media files with python.the most interesting thing is that on motorola g32 and without permissions everything works and when I even manually give permissions to honor through the settings, I see an error. I don't understand how it works, and how i can get access to external storage.

Comment: You told that all before.

Comment: Well then, what else do you need to know to understand my problem, I don’t know what to say anymore,what can help you to better understand the problem maybe I missed something

Comment: That picture was not created by your app. You still did not confirm or deny.

Comment: yes, that picture was not created by my app

Comment: You should be able to read those images from Download folder if the user confirmed the read permission at run time.

Comment: in my code there is a request to read and write to the storage, when I launch the application I confirmed the request to read and write to the storage in the popup window, in the permission settings you can see that access is granted but when I try to read the picture I get an error, and even when manually give permission anyway it gives an error

Comment: Your code does so much more then reading an image. I have no idea where you read your image. Which code line? Why dont you remove all irrelevant code? Why this encrypting and decrypting? Four code lines should be enough to read an image.

Answer (score 0):

my problem was solved by decompiling the apk file and adding: application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" to the AndroidMainfest.xml file
how to decompile an apk file and then compile it back can be seen in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M9fWezuvTUM&t=211s